# How to Develop iPhone/iPad Accessories

Tags: xcode

I want to create hardware accessory for iPhone and iPad but there is very less resources out there. I am not a programmer or engineer. My concept is very simple building a number pad connected through lightning cable. It will have 6x4 keys layout, in this 4 keys can be customize as per need means key a will work as copy(command+c)key b will work as paste(command+v) this keys can be customised in diffrent kind of shortcuts. I dont want a blueetoth connectivity.

Do I need a arduino or raspberry pi kind of device to program and test run a functional prototype?
What kind of cable do I need to sue to communicate with the device? 
What kind of programming langauge do i need to learn?
Do I need to first register for Mfi program or I can do it after I develop the product?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you'll need to join MFI for developing Lightning accessories.

However, you don't need Apple's permission for designing and building your own Bluetooth LE (Bluetooth 4.0) accessories. You should be able to do what you want by programming a Bluetooth LE capable microcontroller to act as a HID device that sends the key events you want. I've not done this specific type of project myself and I'm far from an expert on embedded stuff, but Adafruit have a bunch of resources and development boards on Bluetooth LE using Arduinos and other dev boards. I believe they even have something that already acts as a HID device. I'd start researching in that direction.

Another option is to program a microcontroller to act as a standard USB HID keyboard device, and plug that into the iDevice using the [Lightning to USB Camera adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter). iPads recognise standard USB keyboards without needing MFI approval, but you do need to use Apple's adapter. Note that the adapter allows the USB device to draw very little power (50mA I think) so it will not work with any device that requires more. [The USB3 version of the adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter) has an extra power input and so allows you to attach a USB device that draws more than that.